# Memory/resource limits in Excel 2007 vs 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have a macro that works just fine in Excel 2007, but errors out in 2010 with, "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other applications."

Here's the relevant section of the code:

```
        With .Worksheets(FIRSTSHEETTAB)
            .Range("1:1").Value2 = ps_rng.Range("1:1").Value2
            ps_rng.Range(CStr(start_row) & ":" & CStr(end_row)).Copy destination:=.Range("2:" & max_lines)
        End With
```

I'm not quite sure why this works just fine in 2007, but not in 2010.

Comment: Do you need to copy the entire rows?  What are the values of `start_row` and `end_row` when it errors?

Comment: That was the reason I was using the `Range.Copy` function is because it's supposed to only copy the cells that actually have values in them, and not blank cells, so no, it doesn't need to be the entire row, just the non-blank cells.